# What is the explanation of rewriting P=2^(logN) as log2(P) = log2(N)?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, logarithm

I'm working through the Big-O chapter of Cracking the Coding Interview, and can't wrap my head around one of the manipulations of logarithms that is suggested.

Page 50 of the book tries to show that `O(2log N)` is equivalent to `O(N)`.

The book starts with `Let P = 2log N`, then it makes the claim: "By the definition of log<sub>2</sub>, we can write this as log<sub>2</sub>P = log<sub>2</sub>N"

That claim is where my understanding breaks down. I don't understand how you can reduce `log2(2log N)` to `log2(N)`. If you look at a graph of these two functions, they are clearly different:

[image: graph of log2(2^log(x)) and log2(x)]

This is a step in 'proving' that `N = 2log N` - which also just seems like a false statement. If you graph them again, `N` is a linear function, while `2log N` is a sublinear function.

Any beginner-friendly explanations for how this makes sense? Thanks!

---

Edit to show that `log N` in this case means log-base-2(N):

In this example from the book, `log N` represents the approximate depth of a balanced binary search tree. Just counting the first couple layers of a tree makes it clear that we are working with log-base-2:

```
Which log function gives us the answer "Given the number of 
nodes, what is the depth?" Clearly the answer is log-base-2.

  nodes   depth   log2(nodes)   log10(nodes)
      1       1   0             0             
      3       2   1.58          0.48          
      7       3   2.81          0.85          
     15       4   3.91          1.18          
     31       5   4.95          1.49          
     63       6   5.98          1.80
```

@Kaiwen Chen's answer is spot-on. We're in the world of CS here and the assumed log base is 2. The book adds to this confusion because parts of the example reference an explicit `log2` while the `log N` to describe the depth of the tree is always written with an assumed base of 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CS, a lot of log() functions are assumed to be base 2, so 2^(logx) = x. Your plotting visualization is assuming base 10.

This is a common problem software engineering students deal with. All math courses assume base e, all CS courses assume base 2, and all engineering courses assume base 10.

Comment: Excellent answer. In this example from the book, the "logN" represents an approximate depth of a balanced binary search tree with N nodes.

Just by counting the first few layers, it becomes clear that it's a log-base-2(N) rather than log-base-10(N). I'll update the question to show that.

I guess the big confusion came from the fact that, within this example, the book is sometimes explicit about log-base-2 and other times it's assumed.

Answer (score 3):

This is because **logarithmic functions are the inverse of exponential functions**, i.e. they *"undo" one another*. You can think of logarithmic functions as the following: "*What power do I have to raise a number to, in order to get another number*? Which when you think about it, assuming the same base, sounds a lot like an exponential function. For example,

[image] is **logically equivalent** to: [image], where the *base of the log function is 2*.

So using this knowledge **raising a log function as the exponent of an exponential function results in a cancellation**. It in a way "*undoes*" the exponential. The converse of this is also true and will result in the same outcome. (i.e. the log of an exponential function, with the same base)

As for your question: **Why is *O(2^logN) is equivalent to O(N)?***

This is because, as noted above, the exponential function is raising a logarithmic function of the same base which results in a cancellation, leaving just N to remain. Therefore, the result is O(N)

As for why your chart looks off @Kaiwen Chen gave a good explanation for this discrepancy, involving the differences in base.

Hopefully that helps!